# Type constraint on AnyObject or Any (AnyObject or Any that conforms to a protocol)

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert my Objective-C code to swift.
In Objective-C I have the following protocol:

```
@protocol RWOverlaySelectionDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)areaSelected:(UIView *)view allPoints:(NSArray *)points;
@end
```

and following class has a weak property that reference the protocol (obviously it's defined as weak to prevent strong reference cycle).

```
@interface RWMapSelectionLayer : UIView
    @property(weak, nonatomic) id <RWOverlaySelectionDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Now the Swift equivalent:

the protocol:

```
protocol RWOverlaySelectionDelegate {
    func areaSelected(view:UIView,points:CGPoint[])
}
```

and the class that has a property which conforms to that protocol:

```
class RWMapSelectionLayer:NSObject {
    weak var delegate:RWOverlaySelectionDelegate?
}
```

But I'm getting `'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type 'RWOverlaySelectionDelegate'` compile time error in this line : `weak var delegate:RWOverlaySelectionDelegate?`

Then I tried to convert my property to an `AnyObject` that conforms to `RWOverlaySelectionDelegate` using following syntax:

```
weak var delegate: AnyObject<RWOverlaySelectionDelegate>?
```

Now I'm interfering with Generics and compiler showing: `Cannot specialize non-generic type 'AnyObject'` error.

In another unsuccessful try I changed it to

```
weak var delegate: AnyObject:RWOverlaySelectionDelegate?
```

read it as "Delegate is on type AnyObject where AnyObject should conform to RWOverlaySelectionDelegate"

This is again incorrect because of two colons(:) in a single statement.

Would appreciate if someone can help me to `enforce conformance to a protocol on AnyObject or Any`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have since found a better way of doing this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24104371/2613662).

*Updated for recent Swift versions*

As I mentioned in my comment on CjCoax's answer, prefixing the protocol with `@objc` prevents passing Swift object types (such as enums and structs) to delegate methods.

However, using `: AnyObject` will allow this behaviour while allowing the protocol to be used in a weak variable, though this method is not without its limitations. You can only make classes conform to any protocol that is  marked with `: AnyObject`. I believe that this is a better trade-off than `@objc` provides.

```
protocol MyProtocol: AnyObject {
    ...
}
```

Comment: In swift as of January 2015, this is done as `protocol MyProtocolName: class { ... }`, instead of using the `@class_protocol` declaration.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the recommended solution would be a class-only protocol. From the [Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) protocol page:

> You can limit protocol adoption to class types (and not structures or enumerations) by adding the AnyObject protocol to a protocol’s inheritance list.

So in your example, your protocol definition would look like:

```
protocol RWOverlaySelectionDelegate: AnyObject {
    func areaSelected(view: UIView, points: NSArray)
}
```

With the addition of the `AnyObject` keyword, the compiler should no longer complain.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now (as of Xcode 6.1 GM)

Answer (score 2):

Since swift 4 instead of class we should use AnyObject. From the Swift Programming Language [protocol page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html):

> You can limit protocol adoption to class types (and not structures or
>   enumerations) by adding the AnyObject protocol to a protocol’s
>   inheritance list.

```
protocol SomeClassOnlyProtocol: AnyObject, SomeInheritedProtocol {
    // class-only protocol definition goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
I just need to declare my protocol as follow:

```
@objc protocol RWOverlaySelectionDelegate {
    func areaSelected(view:UIView,points:NSArray)
}
```

and then the class just uses protocol name rather than an AnyObject that conforms to a protocol

```
class RWMapSelectionLayer:NSObject {
    weak var delegate: RWOverlaySelectionDelegate?;
}
```

Protocol declaration which is `@objc protocol RWOverlaySelectionDelegate` require object of `RWOverlaySelectionDelegate` to be a class.
Here is the reference from `The Swift Programing Language` guide provided by apple

> @objc protocols can be adopted only by classes

Comment: The problem with doing this is you can't then pass Swift-only types to the delegate method (such as enums and structs).

Comment: @SteveWilford, agree, just need to stick to this until I find a way to declare a property which is restricted to implement a protocol.