# How does Swift memory management work?

Tags: swift, protocols

Specifically, how does Swift memory management work with optionals using the delegate pattern?

Being accustomed to writing the delegate pattern in Objective-C, my instinct is to make the delegate `weak`.  For example, in Objective-C:

```objc
@property (weak) id<FooDelegate> delegate;
```

However, doing this in Swift isn't so straight-forward.

If we have just a normal looking protocol:

```
protocol FooDelegate {
    func doStuff()
}
```

We cannot declare variables of this type as weak:

```
weak var delegate: FooDelegate?
```

Produces the error:

> 'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type 'FooDelegate'

So we either don't use the keyword `weak`, which allows us to use `structs` and `enums` as delegates, or we change our protocol to the following:

```
protocol FooDelegate: class {
    func doStuff()
}
```

Which allows us to use `weak`, but does not allow us to use `structs` or `enums`.

If I don't make my protocol a class protocol, and therefore do not use `weak` for my variable, I'm creating a retain cycle, correct?

Is there any imaginable reason why any protocol intended to be used as a delegate protocol shouldn't be a class protocol so that variables of this type can be `weak`?

I primarily ask, because in the delegation section of [the Apple official documentation on Swift protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_415), they provide an example of a non-class protocol and a non-weak variable used as the delegate to their class:

```
protocol DiceGameDelegate {
    func gameDidStart(game: DiceGame)
    func game(game: DiceGame, didStartNewTurnWithDiceRoll diceRoll: Int)
    func gameDidEnd(game: DiceGame)
}
```

```
class SnakesAndLadders: DiceGame {
    let finalSquare = 25
    let dice = Dice(sides: 6, generator: LinearCongruentialGenerator())
    var square = 0
    var board: [Int]
    init() {
        board = [Int](count: finalSquare + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
        board[03] = +08; board[06] = +11; board[09] = +09; board[10] = +02
        board[14] = -10; board[19] = -11; board[22] = -02; board[24] = -08
    }
    var delegate: DiceGameDelegate?
    func play() {
        square = 0
        delegate?.gameDidStart(self)
        gameLoop: while square != finalSquare {
            let diceRoll = dice.roll()
            delegate?.game(self, didStartNewTurnWithDiceRoll: diceRoll)
            switch square + diceRoll {
            case finalSquare:
                break gameLoop
            case let newSquare where newSquare > finalSquare:
                continue gameLoop
            default:
                square += diceRoll
                square += board[square]
            }
        }
        delegate?.gameDidEnd(self)
    }
}
```

Should we take this as a hint that Apple thinks we should be using structs as delegates?  Or is this simply a bad example, and realistically, delegate protocols should be declared as class-only protocols so that the delegated object can hold a weak reference to its delegate?

Comment: "If I don't make my protocol a class protocol, and therefore do not use weak for my variable, I'm creating a retain cycle, correct?" No, not correct. Not unless the delegate retains a reference to its host. In the Swift example, that doesn't happen. The DiceGameDelegate has DiceGame parameters in its functions, but it has no DiceGame _property_ that would cause a persistent reference to its host.

Comment: But in most actual use cases, the delegate has a reference to the delegated object.

Comment: Correct, and that is exactly what my answer talks about. - You asked, basically, what's special about this Apple example that does _not_ use a class and a weak delegate, and I told you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a weak protocol reference in 'pure' Swift (w/o @objc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066304/how-can-i-make-a-weak-protocol-reference-in-pure-swift-w-o-objc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should we take this as a hint that Apple thinks we should be using structs as delegates? Or is this simply a bad example, and realistically, delegate protocols should be declared as class-only protocols so that the delegated object can hold a weak reference to its delegate?

Here's the thing. In real life Cocoa programming, the delegate is likely to be an existing class. It is a class because it exists for some other purpose that only a class can satisfy - because *Cocoa demands it*.

For example, very often, to take iOS as an example, one view controller needs to act as another view controller's delegate for purposes of arranging a message back and forth between them. Ownership of the view controllers is dictated by the view controller hierarchy and by nothing else. So, in Swift, just as in Objective-C, you had *better* make that `delegate` property `weak`, because it would be terrible if one view controller suddenly took memory management ownership of another view controller!

So, in the real world of the Cocoa framework, there is serious danger of incorrect ownership or of a retain cycle. And that is the problem that `weak` solves. But it only works, as you rightly say, with classes.

The example in the book, however, is about some objects living off in an abstract made-up artificial Swift-only world. In that world, as long as you aren't in danger of circularity (retain cycle), there's no reason not to use structs and there's no reason to worry about memory management. But that world is not the world you will usually be programming in! And that world is not the framework Cocoa world that your Objective-C delegate pattern comes from and belongs to.

Comment: This question isn't tagged with iOS, and although I've done very little OS X programming, I'm pretty sure I've seen an `NSArray` subclass used as an `NSTableDataSource`.  Doesn't it make at least some sense that I might want to use an array (which is a struct in Swift) as a datasource-type delegate?

Comment: Swift array is a struct but it is bridged to NSArray (the class). -However, in answer to your question, no: in what possible scenario would an array be a data source? Data sources are things capable of answering the data source protocol questions. You'll never have an array do that.

Comment: @nhgrif: Using `NSArray` *as* a table data source (in either OS X or iOS) is a really bad idea. That'd mean extending the `NSArray` class to implement the (`NS`|`UI`)`TableViewDataSource` methods, which would mean *every array in your app* can act like a possible data source for your table view. You've probably seen *classes* that implement table view data source methods *using* an array. Matt's argument holds, at least for Cocoa: the places where Cocoa (Touch) wants a delegate are places that demand a class type, and will probably continue to be.

Comment: @rickster It was an `NSArray` **subclass**.  Just like we'd normally **subclass** `UIViewController`... not extend it...

Comment: @nhgrif You're not supposed to subclass NSArray because it's a class cluster. Wrapper is a better pattern here, for many reasons.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I've spent too much time around people who want to extend everything lately. :) This is still not the usual pattern for a data source, even it works in some cases — Cocoa encourages customization through composition, not subclassing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this example is a bit of an oddity.

Because the example uses a non-class protocol type, it has to expect a possible struct implementing the protocol, which means that the `DiceGame` instance owns its delegate. And indeed, that violates typical assumptions about the delegate pattern.

It doesn't lead to a reference cycle *in this case* because the `DiceGameTracker` is a fictional object that doesn't own the `DiceGame` itself — but in a real-world app it's possible, even likely, that a delegate might also be the owner of the delegating object. (For example, a view controller might own the `DiceGame`, and implement `DiceGameDelegate` so it can update its UI in response to game events.)

That kind of reference cycle would probably turn into a confusing mess if either the game, its delegate, or the type implementing one or both of those protocols were a value type — because value types are copied, some of the variables in your setup would end up being distinct copies of the game (or game's owner).

Realistically one would expect to use reference types (classes) to implement this anyway, even if the protocol declaration leaves open the possibility of doing it otherwise. Even in a hypothetical Swift-only world, it probably makes sense to do it that way... generally whenever you have something with long life, internal mutable state, and a usage pattern that has it being accessed by potentially multiple other actors, you want a class type, even if you can sort of fake otherwise with value types and `var`.

Answer (score 2):

If you must have `structs` and `emums` in your protocol, then if you make your delegate `nil` just before you close the view controller, then this breaks the  retain cycle. I verified this in Allocations in Instruments.

```
// view controller about to close
objectCreatedByMe.delegate = nil
```

It's an optional, so this is valid.

Comment: It should be obvious that this breaks the cycle. But there are plenty of reasons why this isn't really good enough...

Comment: I was just trying to find a solution to the problem. Which I confirmed this is. Not sure why I was down voted for that. Can you expand please.

Comment: I up voted you. You were trying to answer, you didn't put anything wrong that I can tell. And if it were wrong, in a week or two Apple will change the language and you would probably be right. Swift is moving at a rapid pace. I don't get too up in arms about any of it until it plateaus out some. Heck they just added `Set` last week.