# "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" while calling a protocol method

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I've implemented a protocol to get some sort of message, that a game has already finished and passes the time to my controller (Game wrote in SpriteKit). But now I'm having this fatal error after finishing the game and executing the gameEnded method and the app just crashes. Does anyone know why?

Here is my code

GameViewController

```
class AcceleratorGameController: UIViewController {

var time: Float = 0.0
var challengeController: ChallengeViewController!
weak var delegate : GameEnded?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let scene = AcceleratorGame.unarchiveFromFile("AcceleratorGame") as? AcceleratorGame {

        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        scene.viewController = self

        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var dest : ChallengeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ChallengeViewController
    dest.gameHasFinished(time) //Dont know if this does anything...
    println("Segue now!")
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    println("View will disapear")

    delegate.gameHasFinished(self.time) // ###CRASHES HERE!###
}
```

Here is my other ViewController

```
protocol GameEnded : class {
     func gameHasFinished(time: Float)
}

class ChallengeViewController : UIViewController, GameEnded {

var time : Float = 0.0
var acceleratorGameController : AcceleratorGameController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("ChallengeViewController geladen")
    startGame()
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "accelGame" {
        acceleratorGameController = segue.destinationViewController as! AcceleratorGameController
        acceleratorGameController.delegate = self
    }
}
func startGame () {
    println("Start Game")

    self.showAccelGameView()
}
func gameHasFinished(time: Float) {
    println("Game has finished")
    self.time = time
}
func showAccelGameView() {

    println("Show Accel Game")
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AcceleratorGameController") as! AcceleratorGameController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

EDIT:
I did all the things that you told me to, and it still crashes at the same point. Xcode told me to use a delegate. When I do delegate? It works, but that's not what I want. That function has to be called!

```
func gameOver(time: Float) {
    println("Game Over")
    self.time = time
    //delegate!.gameHasFinished(time) still crashes here. added !. i commented it to test the prepareForSegue method
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var dest : ChallengeViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ChallengeViewController
    dest.gameHasFinished(time)
    println("Segue now!") // Wont happen
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true) //Wont happen either. If i call this in gameOver() it works.
}
```

I've put in some `println()` in the `prepareForSegue()` methods, but somehow they won't get executed. Do I have to call them somehow? Here is a screenshot of my segue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK4Ce.png

I also tried putting in one segue the other way round, but it doesn't help either.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVmdP.png (no identifier because it's the only segue.)

I forgot to say that the SpriteKit Game behind this `AcceleratorGameController` calls the `gameOver()` method when it has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how `ChallengeViewController` will initialize the delegate of `AccelerometerGameController`.

In your `prepareForSegue`, you are setting the delegate for the GameController only if the segue identifier is `accelGane`. But when firing the segue in `showAccelGameView`, you are not using this identifier. If you already have the segue setup in your storyboard, use this to fire the segue

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("accelGane", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, some tips :

- Always try to declare your protocols (when refer to the **delegate** pattern) in the following way:

  ```
  protocol GameEnded : class {
      func gameHasFinished(time: Float)
  }
  ```

  With the above way you can then, declare your `delegate` variable `weak` and avoid a strong reference.
- You class `weak var` should be in the following way:

  ```
  class AcceleratorGameController: UIViewController {

     weak var delegate : GameEnded?

     // rest of your code
  }
  ```

And for the last you should keep a reference as a global variable of the class `AcceleratorGameController` to set as your `delegate` in the `prepareForSegue`, like in the following way:

```
class ChallengeViewController : UIViewController, GameEnded {

    var acceleratorGameController : AcceleratorGameController! 

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
         if segue.identifier == "accelGane" {
             acceleratorGameController = segue.destinationViewController as! AcceleratorGameController
             acceleratorGameController.delegate = self
         }
    }
}
```

And the above code should be fix your issue. I hope this help you.

Comment: Why would we have to worry about weak/strong references? I thought ARC was supposed to remove our need to worry about that.

Comment: Yes, and no it could exist retain cycles, you can read more about it in the answer of @matt in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327545/how-does-swift-memory-management-work.

Comment: Yes that makes it clearer. I will have to remember this when adopting the delegate pattern.

Comment: i edited the question with ur tips but it still doesnt work