# EXC_Breakpoint when not forcefully unwrapping

Tags: swift, uitableview, exception, delegates, crashlytics

I'm getting a crash `EXC_Breakpoint` which would indicate to me that there is a `nil` variable being unwrapped?

The line of code it is pointing to is the definition of let **obHeight**:

```
if let qs = Helper_Question.getSection(sid: self.sections[0].sid) {
   let obEnabled = Helper_Type.getId(id: tid)?.enableObservation == 1
   for q in qs {
       let ans = Helper_Answer.getQuestion(aid: selectedAid!, qid: q.Id)
       var baseHeight : CGFloat = 300
       switch(q.qtype){
       case Constants.DEFAULT:
            let obHeight : CGFloat = (obEnabled || ans?.comment != "" || (ans?.answer == "1" && q.hasChildren == 0) || (ans?.answer == "2" && q.hasChildren == 0)) && ans?._na == 0 ? 40 : 0
             ....
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the `?` instead of forcefully unwrapping so I don't think this is the issue? This crash report came into today but I cannot reproduce it on any device. What other reason apart from a `nil` variable would cause a `EXC_Breakpoint` crash? This code is called on action of a button click in a table view cell and uses a delegate to call this code to do some calculations before presenting a splitviewcontroller. selectedAid comes from the button's accessibility identifier which i am setting in the cell for row, always. it is not nil

crash log:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  AppName                        0x100664b30 specialized AuditVC.editBtnTapped(cell : PendingAuditTVC) -> () (AuditVC.swift:294)
    1  AppName                        0x10065fa68 AuditVCAppNamePendingAuditCellDelegate (AuditVC.swift)
    2  AppName                        0x100717468 PendingAuditTVC.editTapped(Any) -> () (PendingAuditTVC.swift:41)
    3  AppName                        0x100717648 @objc PendingAuditTVC.editTapped(Any) -> () + 4302730824
    4  UIKit                          0x1907c6010 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    5  UIKit                          0x1907c5f90 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
    6  UIKit                          0x1907b0504 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 440
    7  UIKit                          0x1907c5874 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 576
    8  UIKit                          0x190d5a550 _UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 4280
    9  UIKit                          0x190d5689c _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1128
    10 UIKit                          0x190d563e0 -[UIGestureEnvironment _deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 404
    11 UIKit                          0x190d5568c -[UIGestureEnvironment _updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 268
    12 UIKit                          0x1907c070c -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3164
    13 UIKit                          0x19079133c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
    14 UIKit                          0x190f8b014 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2400
    15 UIKit                          0x190f85770 __handleEventQueue + 4268
    16 UIKit                          0x190f85b9c __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 148
    17 CoreFoundation                 0x18a61542c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
    18 CoreFoundation                 0x18a614d9c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
    19 CoreFoundation                 0x18a6129a8 __CFRunLoopRun + 744
    20 CoreFoundation                 0x18a542da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
    21 GraphicsServices               0x18bfac074 GSEventRunModal + 100
    22 UIKit                          0x1907f6058 UIApplicationMain + 208
    23 AppName                    0x100044590 main (AppDelegate.swift:23)
    24 libdyld.dylib                  0x18955159c start + 4
```

**UPDATE**

```
open class Question
{
    open var Id : Int = 0
    open var sectionid : Int = 0
    open var question : String = ""
    open var hasChildren : Int = 0
    open var qtype : Int = 0
    open var defaultValue : String = ""
}

public class UP_IA_Answer_m : EVObject {

    public var localId : String = ""
    public var aid : String = ""
    public var sid : Int = 0
    public var qid : Int = 0
    public var answer : String = ""
    public var comment : String = ""
    public var hasChildren : Int = 0
    public var _na : Int = 0
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `? true : false` is unnecessary, leave it out.

Comment: @the4kman done. No idea on the problem? I had 4 crashes with one user.

Comment: Are you sure that `q` is not nil?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the models for `Question` and `Answer`, which I assume is the model names...

Comment: @the4kman q is not nil, no.. as long as qs returns value, none of those values are nil.

Comment: @Laffen I'll add these now but if you're looking for optional properties, there isn't any

Comment: Are you sure you haven't defined a breakpoint in Xcode at the position of `let obHeight ... `?

Comment: @Laffen I don't have a breakpoint there right now anyway, if I had had a breakpoint in xCode at the time of archiving and submitting, would that cause a crash from app users using the app from the AppStore??

Comment: Breakpoints aren't a part of the production build, no.

Comment: @Laffen ok, great. I was very confused by the question so :)

Comment: @Laffen If sections had a count of zero and so sections[0].sid failed, would I expect a exc_breakpoint and perhaps Crashlytics pointed to the wrong line number?

Comment: Well.. that could cause some problems, yes. Make sure you check that the array in fact contains an item at the specific index before trying to access it.

Answer (score -2):

Replacing the values and variable names of the one-liner with "x" to make the error easier to spot:

(x || x?.x != x || (x?.x == x && x == x) || (x?.x == x && x == x)) && x?.x == x ? x : x

I think it is pretty clear where the error happens.

Comment: it's just too darn long for one line? or there is an explicit error I'm missing?

Comment: if it is that it's just too long will splitting it up into one if-else, really change things? I still have to check all of the conditions to the left of the ? and then slot in the assignment for the if and else

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, please elaborate your answer to make it more useful to the OP.