# Is it possible to create class only extension for protocol?

Tags: swift, class, swift-protocols

Class only protocol usage is clear to me. I know I can do something like:

```
protocol HashableClass: class, Hashable {}
```

But I wonder if it is possible to create class only extension:

```
extension Hashable: class {} / extension Hashable where Self is class {} ??
```

The second question is: Is it possible to create non class protocols (counter part of class only protocols)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All classes implicitly conform to `AnyObject`, so you can define
a "class-only extension" with

```
extension Hashable where Self: AnyObject {

}
```

(Also there seems to be no difference between `protocol Foo: class`
and `protocol Foo: AnyObject`, compare
[What's the difference between a protocol extended from AnyObject and a class-only protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176814/whats-the-difference-between-a-protocol-extended-from-anyobject-and-a-class-onl).)

Restricting a protocol to non-class types is – as far as I know –
not possible.