# How to restrict a protocol to value types only?

Tags: swift, swift2

Similar in spirit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066304/how-can-i-make-a-weak-protocol-reference-in-pure-swift-w-o-objc), except, instead of limiting a protocol to only classes, I want to be able to define a protocol that can only be adopted by enums, structs etc.. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

I couldn't find the answer, but through playing around, I've come to the conclusion that you can't. Being that to restrict a protocol to just classes, you precede it with `class` like

```
protocol SomeProto: class {
    func structYourStuff() -> Void
}
```

Making the assumption that this would be consistent among other types, I tried

```
protocol SomeProto: struct {
    func structYourStuff() -> Void
}
```

But Xcode gave me five different errors on one line, which brings me to the conclusion that you can't. I could be completely wrong though, I only started learning Swift about a week ago

Comment: Exactly, we cannot do this. IMHO, it would be a useful extension to the language.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper You got me thinking, perhaps there's some way to build out close functionality since we have the flexibility of custom operators. I can't think of how that would work though.