# Protocol only implemented by struct or immutable

Tags: swift, struct, protocols, swift4

I have a class A that holds an object B implementing the protocol P.

I would like to forbid any modification to object B without class A acknowledging it. Is it possible without any delegate or mutual reference?

Considering that it is possible to specify a protocol that can only be implemented by class type objects `protocol P: class {}` , if there is something similar for `struct`s, I could bind the protocol to a struct, makeing it explicit (being known that structs are passed by value) that the object B has to be set but not edited.

*Long story short:*
**Is there a way to force a protocol implementation to be a struct?**

Comment: No, there is not: [How to restrict a protocol to value types only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623104/how-to-restrict-a-protocol-to-value-types-only).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protocols shouldn't be used this way. Protocols is to define behaviour, not the exact shape of object.

I assume by restricting protocol to structs you want to achieve immutability of it's implementers. If so we can design protocol with getters only

```
protocol Foo {
    var foo: string { get }
}
```

This way `Foo` is immutable and it's can't be changed from anywhere no matter if it's `struct` or `class`.

Then, we can inherit `FooMutable` from `Foo` and add mutators there

```
protocol FooMutable: Foo {
    var foo: string { get set }
}
```

Finally `class A` is the only place where we can mutate `Foo`:

```
class A {
    private var fooValue: FooMutable = FooImpl()

    var foo: Foo { get { return fooValue } }

    func mutateFoo() {
        fooValue.foo = "bar"
    }
}

class FooImpl: FooMutable {
    var foo = "foo"
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i have no control over the holding class and this will perform downcast and checks on the real object type (i know all the problematic coming with this, but i can't do anything about it), so i would like to at least enforce kind of a c++ "const-like" approach. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm not I understand about not having control over holding class. You mean it's in third-party library or what?

Comment: Yes, kind of a third party lib, I guess i'll just adopt an "enforce by documentation" approach.  with a big DO NOT APPLY SIDE EFFECTS note to the doc of the protocol, otherwise yes, your approach would be optimal.

Comment: Does it makes sense to wrap holding class into your own? Or extend it to conform a protocol and then use protocol everywhere. `extension ThirdPartyClass: FooImmutable { }`

Comment: Sadly not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The only I would suggest is to wrap class `A` by a protocol `Q` and define a variable setter of an instance of protocol `P` inside.

```
protocol Q {
    var p: P? { get set }
}

class A : Q {
    var p: P? {
        get {
            // logic
        }
        set {
            //logic
        }
    }
}
```