# What exactly does `: class` do in a protocol declaration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066304/how-can-i-make-a-weak-protocol-reference-in-pure-swift-w-o-objc) explains pretty well how to solve the issue of creating a `delegate` that is `weak`.

Essentially, there are 2 approaches:

**Using the `@objc` keyword:**

```
@objc protocol MyClassDelegate {
}

class MyClass {
  weak var delegate: MyClassDelegate?
}
```

**Using the `:class` keyword:**

```
protocol MyClassDelegate: class {
}

class MyClass {
  weak var delegate: MyClassDelegate?
}
```

I am trying to do some research to understand what exactly the differences between the two approaches are. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) are pretty clear about using `@objc`:

> To be accessible and usable in Objective-C, a Swift class must be a descendant of an Objective-C class or it must be marked `@objc`.

However, nowhere I found some information about what `:class` actually does. Considering the whole notion in detail, it actually doesn't make a lot of sense to. My understanding is that `class` is a keyword in Swift to declare classes. So, here it seems like we are using the keyword `class` itself as a protocol (as we're appending it after the `:` after the protocol declaration).

So, why does this even work syntactically and what exactly does it do?

Comment: Related: [Swift: how to work around issue where weak variable of type 'protocol' is illegal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132190/swift-how-to-work-around-issue-where-weak-variable-of-type-protocol-is-illega)

Comment: Also related: [swift protocol 'weak' cannot be applied to non-class type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33471858/2976878)

Comment: Perhaps also interesting in this context: [What's the difference between a protocol extended from AnyObject and a class-only protocol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176814/whats-the-difference-between-a-protocol-extended-from-anyobject-and-a-class-onl) (and the answer *seems* to be "none").

Comment: @MartinR The first two linked Q&As look like suitable dupe targets to me, so should I vote to close for the first one, and then you dupe hammer with the second (that way both (I think) get linked)?

Comment: I'm not sure. Both answer the question *"what :class actually does"*, but not the relation to `@objc`.

Comment: @MartinR From what I gather from the question (could be wrong), OP understands `@objc` fine, he just doesn't get what `: class` does. I guess we can just wait for the OP to confirm in any case.

Comment: yep, `@objc` is explained in the docs. I'm just struggling to understand the `: class` thing. even from a syntax standpoint it is weird to me that this even works. is that just like a special rule that we are allowed to use this keyword in protocol declarations?

Comment: Lookup "Class-Only Protocols" in the Swift book.

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for, just struggled to use the proper keywords this time as `class` and `protocol` only delivered very general hits on google... :/

Comment: See [Class Only Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID281).

Comment: @nburk Also see the [grammar section of the language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID456) on inheritance clauses which details the specific case of `: class` (look for "class requirement")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:class` ensures that only classes can implement the protocol. And that's *any* class, not just subclasses of `NSObject`. `@objc`, on the other hand, tells the compiler to use Objective-C-style message passing to call methods, instead of using a vtable to look up functions.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! do you have any (official) resources explaining why we can use `: class` in a protocol declaration? the syntax seems pretty weird to me, really would like to read some more about this.

Comment: Do you mean just [Apple's Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID281)?

Comment: oh yeah, that was pretty much what I was looking for, thanks!!