# Delegation of singleton class in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, singleton, protocols

How to use delegate methods of singleton/shared class?
There is one singleton class having some protocol defined but I'm not getting how to access the delegate functions in other classes.

Code snippet for a reference (swift):

> ```
> protocol AClassDelegate
> {
>   func method1()
> }
>
> class A
> {
>    static let shared = A()
>
>    override init() {
>      //initialisation of member variables
>    }
>
>    var delegate: AClassDelegate
>    func foo() {
>
>    }
> }
>
>
> class B: AClassDelegate
> {
>    func bar() {
>       // Note: not getting call to 'foo' method of class 'A'
>       A.shared.delegate = self
>       A.shared.foo()
>    }
> }
> ```

Is this implementation correct?

Comment: Delegate should be always weak.

Comment: You should also add a private init() to your Class A to ensure it is always used as a singleton. As currently you could also declare A() which would not be a singleton.

Comment: Advice: don't allow any class (like class B) to set the delegate of your singleton. Strongly consider passing in the delegate that the singleton uses at init() time.  Your singleton calls delegate's method1 to get something done for it. Class B as the delegate should not be setting up (or calling really) the singleton.

Comment: @Price, yes you are right! but I need to persist some data/calls of the class 'A' through out the app and also want delegation of data to calling classes, hence made it singleton. But to avoid this issue we can broadcast the information using push notification instead of delegates. right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, I'd like to point to:

**1-** Creating a singleton Class should contains:

```
private init() {}
```

That leads to enforce to access the class only by using its shared instance.

**2-** As mentioned in [Max's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42976838/5501940), the delegate should be optional and has a *weak* reference.

**3-** The protocol should be a type of *class*, as follows:

```
protocol AClassDelegate: class
```

*For more information, you might want to check this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066304/how-can-i-make-a-weak-protocol-reference-in-pure-swift-w-o-objc).*

---

Now, let's assume -for testing purposes- that the `method1()` from `AClassDelegate` should be get called when calling `foo()` from `A` class:

```
protocol AClassDelegate: class {
    func method1()
}

class A {
    private init() {}
    static let shared = A()

    weak var delegate: AClassDelegate?

    func foo() {
        print(#function)

        delegate?.method1()
    }
}
```

Let's implement classes that conforms to `AClassDelegate`:

```
class B: AClassDelegate {
    func bar() {
        A.shared.delegate = self
        A.shared.foo()
    }

    func method1() {
        print("calling the delegate method B Class")
    }
}

class C: AClassDelegate {
    func bar() {
        A.shared.delegate = self
        A.shared.foo()
    }

    func method1() {
        print("calling the delegate method C Class")
    }
}
```

**Output** should be:

```
let b = B()
b.bar()
// this will print:
/*
 foo()
 calling the delegate method B Class
 */

let c = C()
c.bar()
// this will print:
/*
 foo()
 calling the delegate method C Class
 */
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for step by step flow!

Answer (score 5):

It's almost correct. You don't take into account that the singleton lives forever (unless you destroy it somewhere), but its delegate may not. So in order to avoid crashes set the `delegate` property to `weak` and optional.

```
weak var delegate: AClassDelegate?
```

This way you shouldn't care if the delegate exists or not.