# implement delegation from a viewController to a DataManager class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I need to send an object (data) from a view controller (embedded in a navigation controller) to a class (or struct) which should manage this data. 
How can I get a reference to this viewController from the class (which has no link of any kind (no segue), or better the struct)  with the set of viewControllers in order to implement a delegation protocol?

I use swift, a storyboard, and I look for any pointer or documentation which could help me to understand how to address this problem. I'm a beginner and I am sorry if this question is far too trivial.

I just need a link to appropriate documentation, many thanks.

Comment: How does “a class (or struct)” get created? What object is responsible for creating and storing it?

Comment: The class or struct is created independently of the view controllers, it's a helper class or a model class. I build it to manage the data that comes from the viewControllers and later to coordinate the flow.

Comment: Share your code how you are displaying you `ViewController` and in which class you have the object of your `DataManager`

Comment: “The class or struct is created independently of the view controllers”. So what? There are three possibilities: you have a global variable (singleton) instance of the helper class, or you have code somewhere that creates the instance, or you create the instance in a storyboard or xib. You need to edit your question to explain how the instance is created.

Comment: It's a rather large code that implements a 24-hour food recall, but the basic is quite straightforward:  I have several view controllers which segues to obtain data from the user. When one validated data is obtained (in the last view controller)  I repeat the operation on some other piece of data.  I want to create an independent class (or classes) which gets the data and start appropriate actions to validate and provide recommendations to the user.

Comment: Would you suggest to use a singleton for the model class ?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might help you. You might wanna read up more on delegation pattern in iOS.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42977875/2396199

Comment: would you recommand to make a singleton class for an helper class ?

Comment: Based on your comments, if the class only perform validations then I would create class methods and would call those methods using class name. eg : Utilities.swift has method performValidation(). Then I would call Utilities.performValidation()

Comment: But from the question it seems like you want to delegate from helper to viewcontroller too, so creating a singleton would suffice.